# How to change UITableView Section color and Text color

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have `UITableView` which populates dates from the plist and Even Section's Title is been populated from plist in `UITableView`.it gives me the default `blue` section color and `White` text color.like this...

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {


NSString *key = nil;
if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView])
{
    key = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:section];
}
else{
    key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
}

//    NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];

 }
```

.
Now I need to change this default text color and Section's color, to do that I am implementing code shown below.But it gives me its own `UIView`.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *tempView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,300,244)];
    tempView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *tempLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,0,300,44)];
    tempLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; 
    tempLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    tempLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,2);
    tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; //here you can change the text color of header.
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSizeForHeaders];
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSizeForHeaders];
        tempLabel.text=@"Header Text";

    [tempView addSubview:tempLabel];

    [tempLabel release];
    return tempView;
}
```

Comment: What do you want your section header to look like? The code in `tableView: viewForHeaderInSection:` method should let you customize the way you want the section header to look.

Comment: ya I want UITableView Section color should be black for each section and Text color on it should be red say...but how to do that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To best customize the look of a table section header, you really need to implement two methods: the first one you already have, and it should work, albeit the results won't be very usable.

The second method is the `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`, which tells the `UITableView` what's the height of the new section, and it can be as simple as this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 50.0f; 
}
```

EDIT: As per the comment, here's the result of your code and defining the header height:

[image: final header label look]

EDIT 2: If you want red text with a black background, change your code for `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` like this:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *tempView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,300,244)];
    tempView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    UILabel *tempLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,0,300,44)];
    tempLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; 
    tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; //here you can change the text color of header.
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSizeForHeaders];
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSizeForHeaders];
        tempLabel.text=@"Header Text";

    [tempView addSubview:tempLabel];

    [tempLabel release];
    return tempView;
}
```

EDIT 3: Ok, so I'll try to merge your code from the first method with the second one. It will look like this:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *tempView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,300,244)];
    tempView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    UILabel *tempLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,0,300,44)];
    tempLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; 
    tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; //here you can change the text color of header.
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSizeForHeaders];
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSizeForHeaders];

    NSString *key = nil;
    if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView])
    {
        key = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:section];
    }
    else{
        key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
    }

    tempLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];
    [tempView addSubview:tempLabel];

    [tempLabel release];
    return tempView;
}
```

This should return a table view section header with the proper label and proper look.

EDIT 4: Just a note on how all of this works: if you use `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` whatever code you put in `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` *will be ignored*. So you need to do the whole setup of the section header, including the proper text in the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection` method.

Comment: ya but it won't change my UITableView Section color and Text color

Comment: It really should. I'll update the question with an image of my final result.

Comment: Also take into account this line of code: `tempView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]`. If you want the view to have an actual background color, don't set it to `clearColor`

Comment: actually u didn't get my question..if i user this `viewForHeaderInSection` and `tempLabel.text=@"Header Text";`ya this will give me new sections ( I don't ant this) `BUT` I want that --> `titleForHeaderInSection` headings should come in sections with updated colors.and text size./

Comment: If you use `titleForHeaderInSection:` you will always get the default look (blue background / white text). If you want custom text, background color, or anything else you *must* use the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`.

Comment: Is there any other way..that I want sections's data `titleForHeaderInSection` for customization

Comment: Hm, I think I know what's bothering you. I'll update my question again in a moment.

Comment: Did you implement the `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` method? Also, try tightening the height of the `tempView` to the height of the `tempLabel`, so to around 44 pixels.